# Facebook APIs using checkins as an entry to raffle

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been exploring ways that it might be possible to promote the business of a friend of mine. One of these ways is by encouraging users to check in to his business, the incentive for this being that they go into the draw to win some kind of prize.

I've been trying to find if the code for this already exists but I might be looking in the wrong places. If it doesn't what would be the best way to do it using the graph APIs.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to check in yourself or your friends?

Comment: I want any user to be able to check in to the page that will be created for the business. The code retrieves those checkins for the week and then randomly selects a winner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Facebook app to check-in to your page/business.

All page check-ins  can be fetched using following request by your code
 
    https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/checkins?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN

If you want to get only specific time period check-ins use `since` and `until` params in query.

You have to parse the json response and store in an array and randomly select the winner.

you can contact the winner using their facebook id and send them a message.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write the code yourself, but it would essentially work like this:

1. Get the user to allow access to the "Raffle" application and get their email address and permissions to look at their check-ins. Email is required to contact the winner.
2. Use a scheduled script (cronjob) to periodically check if the user has checked-in anywhere (in particular, the business you want to promote).
3. Award a raffle ticket for each unique check-in within a 24 hour period.
4. Hold a draw between all the users who checked in on that day or week and award the prize to someone randomly.

Pretty simple flow, but complex code.